# How to link PHP library help to NetBeans?

Tags: php, ide, netbeans

How can I get NetBeans to automatically detect and show help for the core PHP functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like what the [PHP Manual Search](http://plugins.netbeans.org/PluginPortal/faces/PluginDetailPage.jsp?pluginid=21086) plugin does.  Even if you get fed up of using Sun's IDE, and I'm sure I would in under 5 minutes, the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/docs.php) is there.